# Rfid checking continuously for cards

Tags: rfid

Well I am making a automatic car parking system where a any one parking their car will get a card as a token and have to return it before leaving with their cars one card for a slot
And if they don't do so the buzzer will go high
There is also a ultrasonic for each slot to check if the car is present or not.

So far I have managed to do all the part except to check or store a value when the card is removed for that I have been searching for a way to make my rfid reader to check for a tag continuously but all I get so far is my reader only respond when there is a card is present.
I am doing my project any way excluding this part but I would love to add it as it will help to increase the security level.

Comment: Can you please share your code? Also which RFID module are you using

Comment: this is a Q&A site ... not a chat forum ... please ask a specific, answerable question about Arduino

Comment: Do you mean that the RFID reader only reports a tag once when it comes near it and not continously while its near the reader?